# How to calculate the div size to make the script responsive on all devices

Tags: html, jquery, css, responsive-design

I have a script and would like to make it responsive on desktop and mobile devices.

**What I made:** I added a wrapper  (called .cards) and for items / tours (.card). I checked all the tags that are closed, I tried to create a grid layout and set the values for desktop and mobile, but I can't get it work.

**The problem:** if I click a destination (Barcelona, Madrid) the tour list appears below, that is not responsive.

**Live page is:** [link](https://artistatours.com/es/espanol/)

```css
.buttonsX {
  min-width: var(--container-width);
  display: grid;
  gap: 0rem !important;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(calc(var(--container-width)) / 2), 2fr));
  display: grid;
}

.card {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 150%;
  width: 1200px !important;
}

.cards {
  max-width: 1200px;
  display: grid;
  gap: 2rem !important;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(350px, 3fr));
  display: grid;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    font-size: 150%;
    width: 320px !important;
  }
  .cards {
    max-width: var(--container-width);
    /*1200px;*/
    display: grid;
    gap: 0rem !important;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(350px, 1fr));
    display: grid;
  }
}
```

the entire script:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.showSingle').click(function() {
    $('.targetDiv').not('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).hide('slow');
    $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
.showSingle i {
  display: none;
}

.showSingle {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 150%;
  width: calc(var(--container-width) / 1.35) !important;
}

.buttonsX {
  min-width: var(--container-width);
  display: grid;
  gap: 0rem !important;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(calc(var(--container-width)) / 2), 2fr));
  display: grid;
}

.card {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 150%;
  width: 1200px !important;
}

.cards {
  max-width: 1200px;
  display: grid;
  gap: 2rem !important;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(350px, 3fr));
  display: grid;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    font-size: 150%;
    width: 320px !important;
  }
  .cards {
    max-width: var(--container-width);
    /*1200px;*/
    display: grid;
    gap: 0rem !important;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(350px, 1fr));
    display: grid;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="destination_toggle">
  <!--destination toggle begin-->
  <div class="buttonsX">
    <a class="showSingle" target="1">
      <div class="content content-template3 content-destination" style="">
        <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
        <div class="item-destination item-destination-template3 item-destination-1" style="">
          <div class="item-wrapper">
            <!-- Image -->
            <div class="img">
              <img decoding="async" src="https://artistatours.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/pexels-ovidio-rey-51358-scaled.jpeg" class="destination-img" alt="The Most Complete Tour in Barcelona">
              <div class="mask"></div>
              <div class="count-tour">
                <span class="number"> 0 </span> Tours
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Info -->
            <div class="info">
              <h3 class="name"> Barcelona </h3>
              <div class="rating">
                <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-star"></i> 0 Reviews
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--content content-template3
    </a><!--target="1"-->
      <a class="showSingle" target="2">
        <div class="content content-template3 content-destination" style="">
          <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
          <div class="item-destination item-destination-template3 item-destination-1" style="">
            <div class="item-wrapper">
              <!-- Image -->
              <div class="img">
                <img decoding="async" src="https://artistatours.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/5.jpg" class="destination-img" alt="The Most Complete Tour in Barcelona">
                <div class="mask"></div>
                <div class="count-tour">
                  <span class="number"> 0 </span> Tours
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Info -->
              <div class="info">
                <h3 class="name"> Madrid </h3>
                <div class="rating">
                  <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-star"></i> 0 Reviews
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--content content-template3
    </a><!--target="2"-->
  </div>
  <!--buttonX-->
  <div id="div1" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">
    <div class="content content-template3 content-destination" style="">
      <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
      <div class="cards">
        <div class="card">
          <a href="https://artistatours.com/tour_destination/viet-nam/">
            <div class="item-destination item-destination-template3 item-destination-1" style="">
              <div class="item-wrapper">
                <!-- Image -->
                <div class="img">
                  <img decoding="async" src="https://artistatours.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/pexels-enrico-perini-819764-636x636.jpeg" class="destination-img" alt="The Most Complete Tour in Barcelona">
                  <div class="mask"></div>
                  <div class="count-tour">
                    <span class="number"> 0 </span> Tours
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Info -->
                <div class="info">
                  <h3 class="name"> The Most Complete Tour in Barcelona </h3>
                  <div class="rating">
                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-star"></i> 0 Reviews
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <!--The Most Complete Tour END-->
        </div>
        <!--card1-->
        <div class="card">
          <a href="https://artistatours.com/tour_destination/the-genius-of-gaudi-and-modernism/">
            <div class="item-destination item-destination-template3 item-destination-2" style="">
              <div class="item-wrapper">
                <!-- Image -->
                <div class="img">
                  <img decoding="async" src="https://artistatours.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/pexels-tom-darby-6516369-636x636.jpeg" class="destination-img" alt="The genius of Gaudi and modernism">
                  <div class="mask"></div>
                  <div class="count-tour">
                    <span class="number"> 0 </span> Tours
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Info -->
                <div class="info">
                  <h3 class="name"> The genius of Gaudi and modernism </h3>
                  <div class="rating">
                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-star"></i> 0 Reviews
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <!--The genius of Gaudi END-->
        </div>
        <!--card2-->
        <div class="card">
          <a href="https://artistatours.com/tour_destination/street-art-tour-barcelona/">
            <div class="item-destination item-destination-template3 item-destination-3" style="">
              <div class="item-wrapper">
                <!-- Image -->
                <div class="img">
                  <img decoding="async" src="https://artistatours.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/image00001-636x636.jpeg" class="destination-img" alt="Street Art Tour Barcelona">
                  <div class="mask"></div>
                  <div class="count-tour">
                    <span class="number"> 1 </span> Tour
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Info -->
                <div class="info">
                  <h3 class="name"> Street Art Tour Barcelona </h3>
                  <div class="rating">
                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-star"></i> 0 Reviews
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <!--Street Art Tour END-->
        </div>
        <!--card3-->
      </div>
      <!--cards-->
    </div>
    <!--content content-template3 content-destination 1-->
  </div>
  <!--div1-->
  <div id="div2" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">
    <div class="content content-template3 content-destination" style="position: relative; height: 963.9px;">
      <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
      <div class="cards">
        <div class="card">
          <a href="https://artistatours.com/tour_destination/full-madrid-with-actors/">
            <div class="item-destination item-destination-template3 item-destination-4" style="">
              <div class="item-wrapper">
                <!-- Image -->
                <div class="img">
                  <img decoding="async" src="https://artistatours.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/madrid-385104_1280-636x636.jpg" class="destination-img" alt="Full Madrid! (With actors)">
                  <div class="mask"></div>
                  <div class="count-tour">
                    <span class="number"> 0 </span> Tours
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Info -->
                <div class="info">
                  <h3 class="name"> Full Madrid! (With actors) </h3>
                  <div class="rating">
                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-star"></i> 0 Reviews
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <!--MADRID END-->
        </div>
        <!--card1-->
      </div>
      <!--cards-->
    </div>
    <!--content content-template3 content-destination 2-->
  </div>
  <!--div2-->
</div>
<!--destination toggle end-->
```

(I also attaching the page source: [code](https://pastebin.com/MYxRLRPY).)